# Have I shown that convex subsets are connected with correct generality? Any flaws in my proof? (Baby Rudin 2.21(C))

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

$\exists a_1, b \in C_1 \subseteq R^k$ such that there is another pair of points $a_2, b \in C_2 \subseteq R^k$ where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are convex.

A convex subset $C$ is defined pairwise by the equation where $a,b \in C_1$ $\lambda a+(1-\lambda)b \in C$ such that  $0<\lambda<1$.

Let us define subsets $C_1, C_2  \subseteq R^k$
$$C_1 = \{a,b \in C_2, \lambda a+(1-\lambda)b \in C\ : 0<\lambda<1, a,b\in C_1\}$$
Then, we can define a subset
$$C_2 = \{p,b \in C_2, \lambda p+(1-\lambda)b \in C\ : 0<\lambda<1, p,b\in C_2, p\not\in C_1\}$$.
By the definitions of $C_1$ and $C_2$, we know that 
$$b \in C_1 \cap C_2 \neq \emptyset$$
$$\bar{C_1} \cap C_2 \neq \emptyset$$ 
$$\bar{C_2} \cap C_1 \neq \emptyset$$
So $C_1$ and $C_2$ are not disconnected subsets. Thus ${C_1 \cup C_2}$ is a connected set, which shows that every convex subset $C_1$ of $R^k$ is connected.

EDIT: note \bar refers to the closure of the respective sets

Comment: I don't follow your argument. A valid proof would be that convexity requires that the line segment between two points lies in the set; this line segment defines a path between the two points; the convex set is therefore path connected; in any topological space path connected implies connected.

Answer (score 1):

Ahh I think I have figured it out myself. Here is my proof.

WTS:

By the definition of separated sets $\bar{A}\cap B = \bar{B}\cap A = \emptyset \implies E = \{(A\cup B)^C\}\neq\emptyset$.

Let $A_i$ and $B_i$ be the intervals for the elements in the respective k-tuples for all $i, 1\leq i \leq k $. By the definition of separated sets, we can create a open interval for each $E_i$ such that $E_i \cap A_i = E_i \cap B_i = \emptyset$

$E_i = (\sup(\inf(A_i), \inf(B_i)), \inf(\sup(A_i), \sup(B_i)))$

If for an interval $\sup(\inf(A_i), \inf(B_i)) = \inf(\sup(A_i), \sup(B_i))$ make the interval a closed interval.

By construction of this set, we know that a point $p\in E$ is in the intervals between $A$ and $B$ for all elements in the tuple. The construction $p(t) = (1 - t)a + tb$ where $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. We know that $0 < t < 1$, otherwise $p(0)=a\in A$ and $p(1)=b \in B$. We have shown that all intervals of $E$ are intermediate between $A$ and $B$, thus $p(t_0) \in E$ for $t_0\in (0,1)$ and thus not in $A$ or $B$ must exist.

By definition, all convex subsets must satisfy $(1 - t)a + tb\in E; a, b \in E; 0<t<1$. However, as shown earlier, this can only occur when $E = \emptyset$ which implies, $A$ and $B$ must not be separated. Thus, all convex subsets must be continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Do like Rudin does for $\Bbb R^k$: If $A$ and $B$ are non-empty separated in $C$ (a convex subset) pick $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ and define

$$p: [0,1] \to C : \text {by } p(t) = ta + (1-t)b$$

and note that $p$ is continuous (as scalar multiplication and vector addition are) and well-defined (as $C$ is convex).

Then note that $A':=p^{-1}[A], B':= p^{-1}[B]$ (both $\subseteq [0,1]$) are also separated and contain $a$ and $b$ respectively. But Thm 2.47 in Rudin implies that $[0,1]$ is connected and so we have a contradiction, unless $A \cup B \neq C$ and so $C$ is connected.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I figured it out myself yesterday without using Thm 2.47, check it out above.